# Cache response of spring rest api controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching

Is there anyway to cache the response of spring REST API by method parameter? For example, in below code, return the same response (the json serialized data) from cache if the country is already retrieved once.

```
@Controller
public class DataController {

      // Can we cache here by country?
     @RequestMapping(value = "/api/info/{country}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public CountryInfo getCountryInfo(@PathVariable("country")String country){
          return service.getCountryInfo(country);
     }
}
```

Comment: You _can_, but it's best you add a Spring caching mechanism and just add `@Cacheable` to the service method.

Comment: @daniu Why? Caching in controller, I expect to save also the serialization cost.

Comment: Well at the time the code you posted is reached, the serialization is still going to happen (ie encoding of the resulting `CountryInfo` to JSON).

Answer (score 0):

There is a good [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) that shows how you can cache data with Spring.

Even though my answer does not include any code, I would recommend taking a look at it. It is a step-by-step guide that I believe can help you with your problem.