# Caching REST service with Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, caching

I have a REST service that returns a javax.ws.rs.core.Response. This response actually contains a StreamingOutput which is populated in a loop with the objects I stream, something like this:

```
@Cacheable("params")
public Response RetrieveAreas(String params)
{
    (...)
    StreamingOutput adminAreaStream = new StreamingOutput()
    {
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
            {
                try
                {
                     (the loops and object writing/flushing here)
                }
                (...)
            }
    return Response.ok(adminAreaStream).build();
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629449/cache-response-of-spring-rest-api-controller) SO question deals with REST-based Spring caching, but doesn't deal with the StreamingOutput aspect. My questions are:

- Is the caching, when applied at the method level (RetrieveAreas), correctly placed - or should it be placed inside the loop where the objects are loaded and written to the stream ?
- What, besides @Cacheable, is needed to wire up a minimal, working Spring cache for my scenario ? I had a look at [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial) but it is unclear on many aspects such as naming of the cache, the need for a cache manager, the relationship between the ConcurrentCacheManager's string argument and the name of the cache (do they need to be the same or is it just coincidence) etc. 
  If at all possible, please supply a bullet-pointed list of what to do (1. Create a cache manager class, 2. tag a method with @Cacheable, etc.)

Comment: Please take some time to understand the difference between Spring MVC and JAX-RS. They are two completely different frameworks which are in no way compatible.

Comment: I suspect that the caching options that JAX-RS offers aren't helpful in my case, since the relevant thing to watch for (and return cached data for) is not contained in the header of the http call, but in the body (making an ajax call from the html). I think that I have a better chance of retrieving cached objects server-side, rather than sending expires headers - admittedly, I don't fully understand yet if/how the headers are tied to the specific request values that I receive. Would the expiry header allow specific request parameters to be tied to it ?